# readLine() not being saved properly

Tags: c++, qt, c++14

```
void LoadWindow::on_Load_Open_Button_clicked()
{        
    QString load_filepath = ui->Load_FilePath_TextBox->text();      //Get text from textBox
    load_filepath.replace("\\","/");     //Replaces all '\' with '/' for filepath reading

    QFile loadFile(load_filepath);
    if (loadFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))     //Open the file in read-only mode and only reads if file was opened properly
    {
        QTextStream in(&loadFile);
        qDebug() << "line in = " << in.readLine();      //ReadOut 1
        QString x = in.readLine();      

        qDebug() << "x = " << x;        //ReadOut 2
        ExtractInfo(x);

    }else{
        //error
    }
    loadFile.close();

}
```

ReadOut 1 is showing the read in file, however ReadOut 2 is printing "", therefore x isn't being assigned. I have tried many variations including .append() and concatenation, however still not being assigned.All required libraries are included.

Any help is welcome, it may be something stupid.Completed in Qt.

Regards

Comment: The second line of the file must be empty, and so `x` contains an empty string after the second invocation of `readLine`. Alternatively, there is no content after the first line, so `x` contains a "null" QString.

Comment: So if I initialized the x variable and used concatenation or appending, would it fix this issue?

Comment: You could show an example of the file you open, I ran the same code and I had no problems. I use Linux and Qt 5.8

Comment: I have done several tests and I have observed that the only case that happens is that you show when the file has only one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have the reputation required to comment, though I'm curious about what happens if you comment out the line which you have named `ReadOut 1`. I suspect that `in.readLine()` gives two different answers for the two different calls, because it's typical in the implementations of such functions to make them proceed further to the next item (in this case the next line) of the input.

Comment: This fixed it thank you. It was proceeding onto to the next line, therefore the debug actually caused it to not work properly.